# CASE stepper IR remote and Arduino

Tags: arduino, switch-statement, case, stepper

This is my code and i want to control stepper with IR remote. My code work fine but i want to know how can continu my action while a hold button on remote. The HEX code is different when i hold button and i don't know to recall my last function.

```
#include <boarddefs.h>
#include <ir_Lego_PF_BitStreamEncoder.h>
#include <IRremote.h>
#include <IRremoteInt.h>



#include <Stepper.h>
int dir;
int receiver = 6; // Signal Pin of IR receiver to Arduino Digital Pin 6
IRrecv irrecv(receiver);    // create instance of 'irrecv'
decode_results results;     // create instance of 'decode_results'
const int stepsPerRevolution = 200;  // change this to fit the number of steps per revolution
// for your motor

// Ici c'est la nouvelle séquence que j'ai trouvé pour faire fonctionné le moteur (KP4M2) correctement avec le connecteur.
// Reste à mettre dans le bon ordre
Stepper myStepper(stepsPerRevolution, 2, 3, 4, 5);

void setup() {
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
  // set the speed at 60 rpm:
  myStepper.setSpeed(100);
  // initialize the serial port:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}


void loop() {

  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) // have we received an IR signal?

  {
    switch (results.value)
```

Here, i start switch with my HEX code fron IR remote

```
    {

      case 0xB4B49A65:
        //myStepper.step(stepsPerRevolution);//counter clockwise rotation
        //break;
        VrDroite();
        break;

      case 0xB4B45AA5:
        //myStepper.step(-stepsPerRevolution);//counter clockwise rotation
        //break;
        VrGauche();
      case 0xB4B41AE5:
        //myStepper.step(-stepsPerRevolution/10);//counter clockwise rotation
        //break;
        VrMicro();

    }

    irrecv.resume(); // receive the next value
    Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
  }

}
```

Use function for calling action

```
void VrDroite() {


  myStepper.step(+100);


}
void VrGauche() {
  myStepper.step(-stepsPerRevolution);//counter clockwise rotation

}
void VrMicro() {
  myStepper.step(stepsPerRevolution / 10); //counter clockwise rotation

}
void VrNone() {



  myStepper.step(0);



}enter code here
```

Thank

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

This will remember your last keypress.
If the current keypress is a "hold", it will run the same function as the last keypress

```
#include <boarddefs.h>
#include <ir_Lego_PF_BitStreamEncoder.h>
#include <IRremote.h>
#include <IRremoteInt.h>



#include <Stepper.h>
int dir;
int receiver = 6; // Signal Pin of IR receiver to Arduino Digital Pin 6
IRrecv irrecv(receiver);    // create instance of 'irrecv'
decode_results results;     // create instance of 'decode_results'

// last keypress value
unsigned long prev_result_value = 0;
// this key press value
unsigned long current_result_value;


const int stepsPerRevolution = 200;  // change this to fit the number of steps per revolution
// for your motor

// Ici c'est la nouvelle séquence que j'ai trouvé pour faire fonctionné le moteur (KP4M2) correctement avec le connecteur.
// Reste à mettre dans le bon ordre
Stepper myStepper(stepsPerRevolution, 2, 3, 4, 5);

void setup() {
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
  // set the speed at 60 rpm:
  myStepper.setSpeed(100);
  // initialize the serial port:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}


void loop() {

  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) { // have we received an IR signal?

    current_result_value = results.value; // store the result
    if (!prev_result_value)
        prev_results_value = current_result_value; // first time through only.

    if (results.value == HOLD_CODE) // is this a hold code?
        current_results_value = rev_results_value; // make the current result the same as the last keypress.

    //switch (results.value) {
    switch (current_results_value) {

      case 0xB4B49A65:
        //myStepper.step(stepsPerRevolution);//counter clockwise rotation
        //break;
        VrDroite();
        prev_results_value = current_results_value;
        break;

      case 0xB4B45AA5:
        //myStepper.step(-stepsPerRevolution);//counter clockwise rotation
        //break;
        VrGauche();
        prev_results_value = current_results_value;
      case 0xB4B41AE5:
        //myStepper.step(-stepsPerRevolution/10);//counter clockwise rotation
        //break;
        VrMicro();
        prev_results_value = current_results_value;


    }

    irrecv.resume(); // receive the next value
    Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
    Serial.println(current_results_value, HEX);
    Serial.println(prev_results_value, HEX);
  }

}

void VrDroite() {


  myStepper.step(+100);


}
void VrGauche() {
  myStepper.step(-stepsPerRevolution);//counter clockwise rotation

}
void VrMicro() {
  myStepper.step(stepsPerRevolution / 10); //counter clockwise rotation

}
void VrNone() {



  myStepper.step(0);



}
```

Comment: It's exactly what i need. I fix some syntax error but work fine now.
Thank
 +1